# Invalid migration SQL when adding blank=True CharField in Django 1.7.8

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

I'm adding a not null `CharField` to one of my models:

```
channel_class = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I create the migration with:

```
django-admin.py makemigrations webapp
```

Which asks me nothing about default values (see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23405) about default values prompting for `blank=True`).

The SQL generated for this migration is:

```
$ django-admin.py sqlmigrate webapp 0003_auto_20150514_1112
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `webapp_lead` ADD COLUMN `channel_class` varchar(10) DEFAULT  NOT NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                            
ALTER TABLE `webapp_lead` ALTER COLUMN `channel_class` DROP DEFAULT; 
COMMIT;
```

However if I insert that into the MySQL editor that line I get an error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `webapp_lead` ADD COLUMN `channel_class` varchar(10) DEFAULT  NOT NULL;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1
```

It works if I use:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `webapp_lead` ADD COLUMN `channel_class` varchar(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

I.e. if I specify an empty string as default.

My guessing is that the fix for [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23405) introduced a new bug?

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23405#comment:25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24803

It is a bug in django.
In `django.db.backends.base.schema.BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor#execute`, when collected SQL is stored `self.collected_sql`, empty string is passed to formatted string it the wrong way, so resulted SQL comes without `''`.